# How to understand dynamics $\dot x_i=\partial_jA_{ij}$ from skew-symmetric potential $A$?

Tags: potential, field-theory, potential-energy, classical-mechanics

We speak of a dynamical system with a potential if there is a scalar possibly depending on coordinate such that the vector field is exactly the (negative) gradient of the potential. That means each point moves along the direction with the steepest gradient descent. Also we know that the direction of gradient is perpendicular to level set. All of these are about understanding of dynamics in terms of potential.

But how about vector potential? Given a vector potential $A$, what can we say about the system $\dot x=\nabla\times A$? I have no idea what **geometric intuitions** can be drawn from $A$. Even I don't know why we call it a potential if there's nothing similar to scalar potential besides something to do with $\nabla$.

Similar questions I have for $n$ dimension where $A$ is a second-order skew-symmetric tensor and the system is $\dot x_i=\partial_jA_{ij}$.

Thank you for any of your ideas.

Comment: The magnetic vector potential is usually called a "potential" because it is related to the magnetic field by $\mathbf B = \nabla\times\mathbf A$ which is analogous to $\mathbf F = -\nabla V$ in the sense that one obtains one vector field by applying a differential operator to another field (the corresponding potential).

Comment: Also, the dynamical system of classical mechanics is (taking $m=1$) $$\ddot{x}=-\vec{\nabla}\phi(x)$$
So maybe you want to ask which are the solutions and the geometric interpretations of the dynamical system $$\ddot{x}=\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{A}(c)$$
which is the one we can construct with a vector potential.
Why are you interested in just one time derivative of $x$?

Comment: taking the gradient of a scalar, or the curl of a vectorfield is basically the same operation. they can be unified by considering the so called _exterior derivative_ $d$ acting on 0-forms<->scalars and 1-forms<->vectors respectively. the result is a form of degree (n+1), so translating $B=\nabla\times A$ to $B=dA$ where A is a 1-form means B has to be a 2-form. Turns out 2-forms are in three dimensions isomorphic to 1-forms and thus can be (almost) identified with three-component objects - here: the vector $\vec{B}$ Almost because the vector is an _axial_ one, not a proper polar one!

Comment: You might find this useful:  http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9803023  *If potential energy is the timelike component of a four-vector, then there must be a corresponding spacelike part which would logically be called the potential momentum. The potential four-momentum consisting of the potential momentum and the potential energy taken together is just the gauge field of the associated force times the charge associated with that force. The canonical momentum is the sum of the ordinary and potential momenta.*

Comment: @joshphysics That's what exactly I've thought, nothing more?

Comment: @FedericoCarta I think it be more general to be considered as a dynamical system. For classical mechanics, let $x=(q,p)$ and $\phi=\mathcal H$ as Hamiltonian and that is equivalent to Newtonian mechanics. Anyway, regardless of first order or second order of time derivative. Do you have any suggestions on understanding this?

Comment: @nephente What you've said pertains to 3 dimensional case. For general case, potential is defined as second-order skew-symmetric tensor. Would you have comments on that?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I'm sorry but I didn't see its insight. Here potential is always a scalar, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP considers an equations of motion of the form

$$\tag{1}\dot{\bf x}~=~{\bf B}({\bf x}),$$

where the vector field ${\bf B}$ is of the form$^1$

$$\tag{2} {\bf B}~=~{\bf \nabla}\times {\bf A}.$$

In other words, ${\bf B}$ is divergence-free

$$\tag{3}  {\bf \nabla}\cdot {\bf B}~=~0.$$

Eq.(3) is locally eqivalent to eq. (2), cf. [Poincare's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms). Let

$$\tag{4} \Omega~:=~\mathrm{d}x^1 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^2\wedge \mathrm{d}x^3$$

be a volume form in the configuration space. The velocity vector field (1) preserves this volume form

$$\tag{5} {\cal L}_{\bf B} \Omega~=~0,$$

which can be viewed as a [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29) for this system.

--

$^1$A vector field ${\bf A}$ is dual to a two-forms $\frac{1}{2} A_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}x^j$ in 3 dimensions, as nephente mentions in a comment.

Comment: Oh. So much appreciation for answering me after so long a time. I'm actually concerned about any n dimension. Is it true similarly n-volume is conserved?

Comment: The volume form $\Omega$ and the divergence-free vector field ${\bf B}$ generalize to any dimension $n$.